# Why Http status code 404 shows when I click on submit using war file deployed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Image 1. [Successful GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSBNZ.png) 
 
Image 2. [Failed POST when click on submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/804Oq.png) 
Welcome page i.e. `index.jsp` aprears on `localhost:8080/war_filename` 
but when we click on login in index page it shows http status code `404`
Is anyone there, who's having the same issue?
I've copied the war file in `apache\webapps`

**`WebController.java`**

```
@Controller
public class indexController {
    String errorMessage = "Invalid credentials";

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "index.jsp";
    }

    /*********** Login using form ************/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestParam("firstname") String firstName,
            @RequestParam("lastname") String lastName) {
        System.out.println("inside login form");
        Customer object = repository.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName,
                lastName);
        if (object != null) {
            return "home.jsp";
        }
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

**`index.jsp`**

```
<h3>Do Login Here</h3>
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Username" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="lastname" placeholder="Password" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**`home.jsp`**

```
 <body>
 <h3>Operations</h3>
 <form action="/selectusingform" method="get">
    <a href="selectusingform">Select</a>
 </form>
 <table>

    <tr>
        <td><a href="insert.jsp">Insert</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="update.jsp">Update</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="delete.jsp">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="find.jsp">Find</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you went to `home.jsp` or `index.jsp`?

Comment: Thanks for reply,
Yes I did. Welcome page is index.jsp where my login code resides, Its in form and "/login" is action on submit.
index.jsp is coming proper but when I click submit it shows the 404 status.
help me out If you can.
Thanks in adv.

Comment: can you please show the failed POST request. And your successful GET request.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/login this is failed post request

Comment: http://localhost:8080/springJPA-postgreSQL-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ this is main home page get request